# How to convert a string to date format in typescript?

Tags: typescript, date, type-conversion

I have a number 1580294547189 and I want this to be converted into something like this

"Mon Dec 30 2019 16:12:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Thanks in advance

Comment: `new Date(1580294547189 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` constructor can do this for you.

```
const myDate:Date = new Date(1580294547189);
const dateAsString = myDate.toString();
```